# Openfire ubuntu stopped working

Tags: java, ubuntu, openfire

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have installed Openfire 4.1 in that and that was working fine.

But on another day when I have started openfire with following command its not working

```
sudo /opt/openfire/bin/openfire start
```

and tried to open it like **htp://localhost:9090**

I have also checked the status with following command

```
sudo /opt/openfire/bin/openfire status
```

and it shows : `The daemon is running.`

I have also followed following link to setup a Java_home : http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JRE-on-Ubuntu-Linux

So whats wrong with my openfire and **how can I debug it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Shoaib.

I have checked error log and found the error like :

```
2016.03.23 10:09:37 org.jivesoftware.openfire.filetransfer.proxy.ProxyConnectionManager - Error creating server socket
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
```

and I think that error was due to my domain was changed.

Now we are working in one office and assigned dynamic IP to all machines, so its changing IP each and every time and thats the reason its stopped working.

I have changed by IP to previous once,which I have added at the time of installing openfire, and it works...

Answer (score 1):

For Debugging, you should take look at the logs located under /opt/openfire/logs directory.
Check info.log, error.log for clues.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your great help.